# How to encode string to Unicode Powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode

I need to convert a string characters to unicode.

To be simple, if i have this string : `"i_Id Mega (hex)"`,
i want to encode this and get : `"i_Id_x0020_Mega_x0020__x0028_hex"`

I don't find a way to do this in powershell.
All help is welcome !

Thanks,
Tristan Sébillet

Comment: You apparently want to replace space characters with `_x0020_`, open brackets with `_x0028_` and remove closing round brackets? What have you tried already and what failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use several regex `-replace` actions:

```
"i_Id Mega (hex)" -replace ' ', '_x0020_' -replace '\(', '_x0028_' -replace '\)'
```

Result:

> ```
> i_Id_x0020_Mega_x0020__x0028_hex
> ```

Comment: That's what i want but i need to do it for all special characters. So the -replace solution is a bit long..

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$inStr       = "i_Id Mega (hex)"
$outStr      = ""
$uniChars    = " ("
$removeChars = ")"

foreach( $char in [char[]]$inStr ) {

    if( $uniChars.Contains( $char ) ) {
        $outStr += '_x' + "{0:x4}" -f [char]::ConvertToUtf32([string]$char ,0) + '_'
    }
    elseif( !$removeChars.Contains( $char ) ) {
        $outStr += $char 
    }
}

$outStr
```